# How to see the report of "Track Event"

Tags: marketing-cloud

I've set up the code follow to this docs
http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/web_and_mobile_analytics/web_analytics/core_components/collect/collect_installation/track_event/

But i can't see the report of this track.
Do you have any idea how to see the report of all events?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide more details, post what you have done and the error you are receiving.

Comment: I've add the script to my web page. It's already push the trackEvent to the MarketingCloud Server. But after i enter the Web&Mobile Analytics view. I can't find the report of those events. All i can see are tiles explain about "Visitor Location", "Devices", "Page Popularity" but not track events. Do i have to add another tiles or it's in another menu? Please advise.